How to restore data from binlogs for a specific DB
Recently an admin deleted all data from a specific table by mistake. I would like to restore these but my bin files cover all the dbs on the mysql server.
Is it possible to restore rows that have been deleted via the binlogs?
It seems whenever I grep to try and pull out any information from the binlogs I see only:
#241201 12:31:26 server id 1  end_log_pos 101285300 CRC32 0xc3d13244    Table_map: `warhammer`.`posts` mapped to number 107711

#241201 12:31:26 server id 1  end_log_pos 101286351 CRC32 0xc34d03e6    Table_map: `warhammer`.`posts` mapped to number 344`

